# Getting null from 'getLastKnownLocation' on SDK

Tags: android

I have a problem related to the Location API.

I tried the following code:

```
LocationManager lm = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
Location loc = getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
```

`loc` is always `null`, when `getLastKnownLocation()` is called.

What is wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Along with the permissions in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file, have you registered a location listener?

```
LocationManager lm = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
Location loc = getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS, 100, 1, locationListener);
```

Then have a method, in this case `locationListener`, to complete your task

```
private final LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    latitude = location.getLatitude();
    longitude = location.getLongitude();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're running the code in the emulator, any calls to get the GPS location will return null until you explicitly update the location (via [Eclipse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_%28software%29) or [ADB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_Debug_Bridge)).

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem as you, I always receive a null Location object, But finally it was solved in an easy way. You must have a valid GPS location, so, if the GPS is not enabled and you dont't have enough signal, the Location object will be ALWAYS null.

Answer (score 1):

Have you set the permissions in your AndroidManifest.xml?  You need these permissions in order to access the user's location with an application:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />
```

Comment: Actually, the MOCK_LOCATION is not needed -- it's just for development/testing

Answer (score 0):

Here's something you can use:

```
LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
String bestProvider = lm.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
Location loc = lm.getLastKnownLocation(bestProvider);

last_lat = loc.getLatitude();
last_lng = loc.getLongitude();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need the instance Of LocationManager like this:

First Instance:

```
   LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
```

Wrong:

```
Location loc = getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
```

Correct:

```
Location loc = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
```