# Please Help me for gtting the current location of the Android phone

Tags: android, location, locationmanager

Please Help me for creating an application for getting the current location of the android phone.

Thank you.

Comment: Similar Question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1916568/getlastknownlocation-getting-null-on-sdk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just implement the LocationListener in your activity

Answer (score 0):

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#getLastKnownLocation%28java.lang.String%29 ?