# getLastKnownLocation() return always null on device

Tags: android, google-maps

In the code below `getLastKnownLocation()` always returns null on a device, even when I am getting `Provide = internet`. It was working fine but know it's returning a null value. I am using a Galaxy Tab version 2.2.

```
public void find_Location(Context con) {
  Log.d("Find Location", "in find_location");
  this.con=con;
  String location_context = Context.LOCATION_SERVICE;
  LocationManager locationManager =
    (LocationManager)con.getSystemService(location_context);
  List<String> providers = locationManager.getProviders(true);
  for (String provider : providers) {
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 1000, 0,new LocationListener() {
      public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {}
      public void onProviderDisabled(String provider){}
      public void onProviderEnabled(String provider){}
      public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status,Bundle  extras){}
    });
    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
    if (location != null) {
      lat = location.getLatitude();
      lng = location.getLongitude();
      Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(AdvanceSearch.this,
        Locale.getDefault());List<Address> addresses;
      try {
        addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(lat,lng,100);
        countryname=addresses.get(0).getCountryName();
        eexit e = new eexit();
        statename= addresses.get(0).getAdminArea();
        cityname=addresses.get(0).getLocality();
      } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: You need time to get fix. Check when `onLocationChanged` is called.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1916568/getlastknownlocation-getting-null-on-sdk?rq=1
check this 1 out. It's exact duplicate to your question.

Comment: i waited for arrount 4 min but onLocationChanged never called

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would focus on this line first. Your `requestLocationUpdates` has a `minDistance` set at 0.

Play around with the `minDistance`, I think that is where your problem is.

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 1000, 15, new LocationListener() {
```

---

**Edit:**

In addition I would add a `Log` to your `LocationListener` methods. Doing this has helped me quite a bit.

Here is an example of my early `LocationListener` script:

```
public LocationListener jLocListener = new LocationListener() {
    //class findMe implements LocationListener {
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        try {
            lat = location.getLatitude();
            lon = location.getLongitude();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("onLocationChanged", "FAILED: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        Log.i("LocationListener", "onProviderDisabled");
    }
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        Log.i("LocationListener", "onProviderEnabled");
    }
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        Log.i("LocationListener", "onStatusChanged");
    }
```

Comment: i am geeting this message  /MapActivity(5867): Couldn't get connection factory client

Comment: Are you trying this on the emulator? If so make sure that the emulator has GPS support selected under the hardware section. Also do you have `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COURSE_LOCATION" />` and `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />` in your manifest?

Comment: i am checking it on Device , it take too long to get Current location through this code, that impact that its not working properly , and its slow down my app , is there any fix to this ?