# NullPointerException - location is null?

Tags: java, android, android-location

I am getting a nullpointerexception on this line:

```
double latitude = location.getLatitude();
```

Here is the block of code that is causing me issues:

```
//Get the current location
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

//Zooms into the current location when the activity is started
double latitude = location.getLatitude();
double longitude = location.getLongitude();
```

How am I getting a nullpointerexception when I'm intializing my Location variable and LocationManager variable?  What is wrong with my code?

Comment: plz add more code where you are using current code in Activity,Service,.. and also add logcat results with question to get more help from us

Comment: Maybe `Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);` this doesn't return a valid location.

Answer (score 1):

If nothing on the phone is actually listening to the location updates then the phone will not update the last known location.  In this case, if the value is too out of date it will return null (otherwise it could return some very stale data).  If you want to ensure that you get a location you need to register for updates yourself.  Then, after the first update occurs you can call getLastKnownLocation whenever you want.

Answer (score 0):

Along with the permissions in your AndroidManifest.xml file, have you registered a location listener?

```
LocationManager lm = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
Location loc = getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS, 100, 1, locationListener);
```

Then have a method, in this case `locationListener`, to complete your task

```
private final LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    latitude = location.getLatitude();
    longitude = location.getLongitude();
}
```

Please refer to top answer here: [Getting null from 'getLastKnownLocation' on SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1916568/1065197)

Answer (score 0):

This line doesn't mean that you'll definately get not-null `Location`

```
Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
```

You're getting `null` just because there is no "last-known" location.

Answer (score 0):

The location returned by `locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider)` must be null.  Check that your app has all the required permissions in the manifest for accessing location.  Also, rather than `getBestProvider(...)` I suggest you try

```
Location location_gps = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
Location location_network = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
```

and see whether either or both of them are null.  You can also look at

```
bool isGpsEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
bool isNetworkEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
```

to see if you can spot any problems there.

A more comprehensive methodology is to register for location updates by creating a class that implements the `LocationListener' location listener serivce.  The problem with getLastKnownLocation is that it may be stale or null, so unfortunately that's probably necessary if you want your app to be reliable.