# Android Studio - LocationManager ( get longand latitude )

Tags: android-studio, geocoding, locationmanager, android-gps

I want to get the longitude and latitude, I have the following code in my project but the `Log.d("",);` is empty.

```
        LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return;
    }
    Location location = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    double longitude = location.getLongitude();
    double latitude = location.getLatitude();
    String _longitude = String.valueOf(longitude);
    String _latitude = String.valueOf(latitude);
    Log.d("LocationManage",_latitude + _longitude);
```

I hope someone can help me.

Comment: Have you considered [using a listener for the location](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1916986/7540393) ?

Comment: Thanks @ArthurAttout